# Bind a Combobox Selected Item with DataGrid Column

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid

I am new in WPF. I have 2 controls Combo box and DataGrid. They are bind with DataSource1{**ProperyX**} and DataSource2{PropertyA, ProperyB, **ProperyX**}. I have a requirement  that the Combo Box value should get selected whenever any row is getting selected in DataGrid (i.e if a row selected having the value of Column **ProperyX** is "JHON" then the same "JHON" should get selected in Combobox) with DataSource2 ProperyX column.

Comment: <ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemModel, Mode=TwoWay}"/> with <DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemModel, Mode=TwoWay}" /> SelectedItems should be the same property in you viewmodel. Don't forget the OnPropertyChanged event in setter.

Comment: The simple approach is to set the `SelectedValuePath` property of both controls to "PropertyX" and bind their `SelectedValue` properties to each other, e.g. with an ElementName binding. It would however make sense to create a common view model to which control are bound. Search the web for MVVM.

Comment: @PéterHidvégi Note that the controls apparently use different item classes. Besides that, setting Mode=TwoWay on a SelectedItem binding is redundant. The property binds two-way by default.

Comment: @Clemens you are right, but in this way you can write two different property with setters which refers to each others.

Comment: @PéterHidvégi Sure you could, but why would you do that when there is SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath?